# Retrieve list items with JScript/jQuery - reusable function isn't working as expected - SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I'm having a bit of trouble creating a reusable function to get various data from SharePoint lists.  I'm at a loss as to what to do - everything I've read/searched for implies this code *should* work, but it's not.

I have the following function:

```
    // Pulls data from a SharePoint list and updates the target element
    // Usage:
    // Input:
    //              listName: SharePoint list name we're looking up
    //              camlXML: XML for the CAML filter we use
    //              fieldName:
    //              context:
    //              element:

    function getSPListData(listName, camlXML, fieldName, context, element) {
            var clientContext = context;

            var SPList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);

            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.set_viewXml(camlXML);

            var collListItem = SPList.getItems(camlQuery);

            var includeStatement = "Include(" + fieldName + ")";

            clientContext.load(collListItem, includeStatement);
            var newText = "";
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                    function (sender, args) {
                            var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

                            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                                    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                                    newText = newText + oListItem.get_item(fieldName);
                            };
                            element.text(newText);
                    },
                    function (sender, args) {
                            element.text("Error -> getSPListData -> clientContext.executeQueryAsync request failed");
                    }
            );
    };
```

I have another function which I'm using to create elements within a list.  This work - I'm sure there's a way to do it better because of my ignorance with the SharePoint API.

```
    function linkIDs(context, SID1, field1, SID2, field2, list) {
            //var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var clientContext = context;

            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(list);
            var item = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            var oListItem = oList.addItem(item);

            var Item1LookupField = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
            var Item2LookupField = new SP.FieldLookupValue();

            Item1LookupField.set_lookupId(SID1);
            oListItem.set_item(field1, Item1LookupField);

            Item2LookupField.set_lookupId(SID2);
            oListItem.set_item(field2, Item2LookupField);

            oListItem.update();

            clientContext.load(oListItem);

            return clientContext;
    };
```

Comment: What is not working? Did you debug the code and check? Also check F12 for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a decent way to accomplish this, however I don't use CAML, instead I rely on the REST API.

```
// Queries a SharePoint list using the REST API to retrieve items.
// Remember - we're dealing with asynchronous queries
// Input fields use syntax here: 
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx
// Input:
//      listName: SharePoint listname
//      queryItem: List fields
//      queryFilter: Any filters
//      sortMethod: Sort order
//      expandParams: Field expansion params
// Returns:
//      AJAX Object
function getListItem(listName, queryItem, queryFilter, sortMethod, expandParams) {
    /*
        /(.*?)SitePages.+/
            1st Capturing group (.*?)
                .*? matches any character (except newline)
                    Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
                SitePages matches the characters SitePages literally (case sensitive)
                .+ matches any character (except newline)
                    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    */
    var URL = $(location).attr("href").replace(/(.*?)SitePages.+/g, "$1") + "_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName;

    if (queryItem || queryFilter || sortMethod) {
        URL = URL + "?";
    }

    if (queryItem) {
        URL = URL + "$select=" + queryItem;
    }

    if (queryFilter) {
        if (queryItem) {
            URL = URL + "&$filter=" + queryFilter;
        } else {
            URL = URL + "$filter=" + queryFilter;
        }
    }

    if (sortMethod) {
        if (queryItem || queryFilter) {
            URL = URL + "&$orderby=" + sortMethod;
        } else {
            URL = URL + "$orderby=" + sortMethod;
        }
    }

    // Assume if we have expandParams it's not the first element
    if (expandParams) {
        URL = URL + "&$expand=" + expandParams;
    }

    var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        async: true,
        cache: true
    });

    return ajaxCall;
}
```

You then call this function like:

```
    var ID = IDfromSomewhere;
    var listName = "testList";
    var fieldName = "field1, field2, field3";
    var queryString = "field1 eq '" + ID + "'";
    var sortMethod = "field1 asc, field2 asc";

    var query = getListItem(listName, fieldName, queryString, sortMethod);
```